# Start menu problems even with less than 500 items

Tags: windows-10

I have windows 10.

I've made all the latest updates.

I've read in some other articles , that start menu has a limits of 500 or 512 items.

But with my system I have this problem with 232 or more  items.

When I have 231 items I have no problem.
When I install another program that adds 2-3 other shortcuts , many of the shortcuts of start menu disappear.
I've done a system restore at the point before program installation.
Everything back to normal.
I try to install another program that add 2 shortcuts.
The problem appear again.

**Updated**
I think there's no any rule on this problem.
I have another PC with windows 10 , that has this problem with 116 items.

Comment: Is User Account Control (UAC) enabled?

Comment: UAC is disabled

Comment: Try enabling it and restarting.

Comment: I've made 2 tests  The first test was made with UAC enabled. The second test was made with UAC disabled. The problem is the same.

Comment: [See if answer by SnoProblem helps](http://superuser.com/questions/955139/some-start-menu-shortcuts-are-missing-on-windows-10)

Comment: To get a count of startmenu items, run this in powershell: `Get-StartApps | measure`

Comment: I know how to get the number of start menu items. If you read my post , I've included the exact number

Comment: @Moab I've tried the solution on that link , but without success. the strange is that the shortcuts are disappear and doesn't exist anymore on start menu folder.

Comment: Strange problem indeed.

Comment: I have created again all the missing shortcuts , and I've copied inside the start menu folder. After that all the shortcuts appear correctly on start menu. After that I have installed a new program , that add 1 shortcut , and the problem appear again.

Comment: if UAC is disabled the new startmenu doesn't even run. YOu may only have moved the slider down (which still leaves the UAC on since Win8). Use a better Startmenu: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557