# Windows 10 Start Menu not showing all shortcuts?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, start-menu

Before someone calls this a duplicate, all the other answers that I've found for this issue claim the problem was fixed in one of the technical previews; however, I'm on the latest version of Windows 10 (having upgraded from Windows 7 a week or so ago) and the problem persists.

I've tried running `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` in powershell. It completed but nothing changed. I've restarted my computer many times before and after that change.

I've checked several times. I have waaay more shortcuts in the start menu folder than are visible in the start menu. If I run `Get-StartApps | measure |findstr Count` in powershell it reports 878 items.

This problem is horrible because typing into the start menu is my primary way of launching programs and it's broken. I've searched for ages and I don't know what else to try. Please help!

Comment: See if the Start menu [troubleshooter](http://aka.ms/diag_StartMenu) helps. ([via](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/12385/windows-10-troubleshoot-problems-opening-start-menu-cortana))

Comment: **See Also** [Some start menu shortcuts are missing on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/955139/180163)

Comment: @KyleMit Yes, as I linked in my answer, one of the answers from that post solved my problem.

Comment: Clonkex, yeah, both approaches are totally fine.  Linking the issues as related helps search engines and future users find relevant answers, but there's nothing wrong with this post existing too.  Upvoted as well.  I delete this comment in 24 hrs since it's not informative long term.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aha! I seem like an idiot now, answering my own question so soon after asking it, but hopefully this will help someone else. [This post](https://superuser.com/a/967016/623023) (which I had seen several times but thought I'd already tried) fixed it for me! After doing what he suggested (which was to go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows`, right-click the Start Menu folder and select Properties, tick Hidden then click apply and apply to all subfolders and files, then un-hide everything and click ok), within a few minutes I noticed the All Apps buttons on my start menu was saying "new", and a few minutes later all my shortcuts were correctly visible and searchable!

FINALLY I can use Windows 10 properly!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this answer. This has been bugging me for WEEKS. Windows 7 I used to be able to just drag things into the start menu and then I could [winkey]appname[enter]. It drove me crazy to not have this in windows 10 (until now).

Comment: This actually made it worse for me : ^/

Comment: ah, no worries @Clonkex , after all is the system's fault not yours.. cheers