# How to make an element fill the width of the browsers window with uBlock?

Tags: css, ublock-origin

For example, this page at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1808154/windows-10-explorer-no-longer-starting), the main content of the page is squished, so its hard to read or focus on it. I would like to take it from how it is currently [rendered](https://i.imgur.com/4kjUKes.png) to [this](https://i.imgur.com/vQZpRCE.png).

The after screenshot link is the best I could do to get my browser to render what I want to achieve with uBlock, I don't want to change the font size, just the width of the element.

According to the picker, the element I am interested in filling the browser width with is called `superuser.com###content`.

I first tried this but it does not seem to have any affect:

```
superuser.com###content:style(width: 100vw !important;)

!Hide Right Sidebar
superuser.com##.js-sticky-leftnav.left-sidebar--sticky-container
!Hide Left Sidebar
superuser.com##.ps-relative.js-pinned-left-sidebar.left-sidebar
```

Then I tried:

```
superuser.com###mainbar > div:style(width:100vw !important;)

!Hide Right Sidebar
superuser.com##.js-sticky-leftnav.left-sidebar--sticky-container
!Hide Left Sidebar
superuser.com##.ps-relative.js-pinned-left-sidebar.left-sidebar
! This gets in the way too
superuser.com##.show-votes
```

But I just end creating a whole new mess, as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/ipDvcCh.png). Any further changes I just end making it worse. I pieced together most of this by looking at other questions and searching for CSS properties such as `100vw`.

I don't seem to be getting anywhere though. Can anyone show me how to do this properly? I would greatly appreciate an example.

Comment: 1st image shows as removed, 2nd shows a narrow column. Please check your links.

Comment: @Tetsujin hey pardon me, I corrected the removed image link. As for the other one, the best way I could render an example of it filling the browser windows width was to zoom in all the way with the browsers zoom in function. I made note of that at "he after screenshot link is the best I could do to get my browser to render..."

Comment: OK, thanks. You can remove the left sidebar in prefs, once you're signed in. There is a width limit, though, whatever viewport you have [which I also find irritating, see - https://i.stack.imgur.com/r84hj.png ]. The right sidebar stays. idk anything about uBlock, so I'll leave that to others more competent. Wish you luck.

Comment: The best tool is probably GreaseMonkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
superuser.com###sidebar
superuser.com###left-sidebar
superuser.com##.container:style(width: 100% !important; max-width: 100% !important;)
superuser.com###content:style(width: 100% !important; max-width: 100% !important;)
```

You need to check every related element that sets `width`, browser's `Inspect element` type of functionality and reviewing nearby HTML is required. You missed `.container`. The 2nd problem is lack of `max-width` manipulation, which overrules `width`.

Also, use IDs wherever available rather than classes. You want to be as specific as possible with this kind of tools.

Comment: "use IDs wherever available rather than classes. You want to be as specific as possible with this kind of tools." got it! will keep that in mind for sure. Thanks